# Unable to calculate Total in my shopping-cart

Tags: javascript, angular

I Have created a shopping cart with 2 components(Productlist and cart list). when I click on the 'add to cart' button in the product list it is successfully moving into the service file and from the service file to 'cart list' but Total was showing undefined. Please help me to solve this cart Total issue.

**Product-list.ts file**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ProductService } from '../../../service/product.service';
    import { CartService } from '../../../service/cart.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-product-list',
      templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
    })
    export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      Productlist = [];
    
    
      constructor(private productservice: ProductService,
                  private cartservice: CartService) {
    
        this.Productlist = this.productservice.send()
       }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      saveproduct(item) {
    
        this.cartservice.get(item)
    
      }
    }
```

**cart service file**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CartService {
    
      cartproducts = [{Name: 'Mobile', Price: 13000, Qty: 1}]
    
      constructor() { }
    
    
      send() {
    
        return this.cartproducts
      }
    
       get(items) {
    
        this.cartproducts.push(items)
    
        console.log(this.cartproducts)
       }
    }
```

**cart list file**

```js
    
    import { Component, OnInit, ɵConsole, ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature } from '@angular/core';
    import { CartService } from '../../../service/cart.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cart',
      templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
    })
    export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    
      cartlist = [];
    
      Total: number;
    
      constructor( private cartservice: CartService) {
    
        this.cartlist = this.cartservice.send()
    
        console.log(this.cartlist);
    
        console.log(this.Total);
        
       }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.cartlist.forEach((_e: any) => {
    
          this.Total += (_e.qty * _e.price);
      
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

When the `Total` property has been created, it is `undefined` by default until you assign it a value. You do assign a value to it in the `ngOnInit` but you calculate on an `undefined` value, so it returns `undefined` as well. Give `Total` a default value like so:

```
    ...

    Total: number = 0;

    ...
```

Also the code you put in `ngOnInit` to calculate the `Total`, would be better placed in a `get` property. This way, Total will always be calculated when it's requested instead of pre-rendered and only calculated once. In that case your code would look like:

```
    get Total(): number {
      let value = 0;
      this.cartlist?.forEach((_e: any) => {
          value += (_e.qty * _e.price);
        });
      return value;
    }
```

Comment: I Tried it but the issue was not solved..... Still, it is showing undefined.

Comment: If you assign a default value of 0, then it should return 0 at least. Can you update your code in the post here or set up a test environment in Stackblitz?

Comment: Maybe because of a `ng serve` restart. From time to time that helps if your code doesn't seem to compile.